# How to restore function key F3-F5 functionality in Gnome under Wayland on 18.04?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, function-keys

Recently (in December 2018), function keys F3, F4 and F5 broke for a specific keyboard in Gnome on Wayland on Ubuntu 18.04 such that pressing the keys does not result in the function key being passed to the app but results in an overlay showing  (flipped horizontal).

It doesn't happen with a different keyboard. With the affected keyboard it happens with multiple computers.

What kind of per-keyboard state could result in these three function keys mapping to something that Gnome reacts to with a  overlay?